# FileChannel.truncate(...) method truncates at wrong position

Tags: android, file, kotlin, fileutils

I am using the [FileChannel.truncate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel#truncate(long)) method to remove the last part of a file, from the text "metadata" until the end:

```
override fun truncate(file: File) {
    val fileAsText = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, Charset.defaultCharset())
    val metadataPosition = fileAsText.indexOf("metadata")
    val channel = FileOutputStream(file, true).channel
    channel.truncate(metadataPosition.toLong())
    channel.close()
}
```

While debugging I can see that the variable `metadataPosition` has a certain value, which is correct when checking it in the `fileAsText` String. Note that the "metadata" text only appears once in the file. However, when the `channel.truncate(metadataPosition.toLong())` line is executed, the truncation is performed in a previous position and the file is smaller than expected, losing some of the information.

I have no clue about the reason for this, what could it be?

Comment: String indices don't correspond to file indices, b/c of character encoding?

Comment: @greeble31 It was the encoding, indeed. It looks obvious now. Thanks.